# adding structs to a map c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, maps

I am having some problems adding two structs to a map where the value is a vector.

```
std::map<Orders, std::vector<Items>> records;

        for(std::vector<StdCardConfirmationReceipt>::iterator vIter= mvCardConfirmationReceiptList.begin(); vIter != mvCardConfirmationReceiptList.end(); ++vIter)
        {

            Orders order = {(*vIter).getOrderIdOrderCentral,(*vIter).getFulfillmentOrderIdOrderCentral};
            Items item = {(*vIter).getItemIdOrderCentral,(*vIter).getLineItemIdOrderCentral, (*vIter).getItemFulfillmentStatusOrderCentral, (*vIter).getFulfillmentExceptionOrderCentral};

            if (records.find(order) == records.end())
            {
                records.insert(std::make_pair(order,item));
                //records[order];
                //records[order].push_back(item);
            }
            else
            {
                records[order].push_back(item);
            }
       }
```

When I try to use the 'records.insert()' with either 'pair' or 'make_pair' functions, it gives me this error that I don't really understand.  The comment lines in the 'if-statment' seem to work but I am not sure if that's the correct way to insert new entries into a map. Below is the code for the two structs, if that helps.

```
struct Orders
{
    std::string sId;
    std::string sFulfillmentOrderId;
};

struct Items
{
    std::string sId;
    std::string sLineItemId;
    std::string sFulfillmentStatus;
    std::string sFulfillmentException;
};
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Pop quiz, what's more readable, "for(std::vector<StdCardConfirmationReceipt>::iterator vIter= mvCardConfirmationReceiptList.begin(); vIter != mvCardConfirmationReceiptList.end(); ++vIter)", or "for (auto &order:mvCardConfirmationReceiptList)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would have helped if you actually *included the error message*, it's easy to see in this case that you are trying to insert the wrong type into your map.

The `records` container maps a key type of `Orders` to a value type of `std::vector<Items>`.  But your insertion line is trying to add a single `Items` instead of `std::vector<Items>`.

You should create a vector with that item in it.  There are a few way to do it.  Simplest is:

```
records.insert( std::make_pair( order, std::vector<Items>( 1, item ) ) );
```

The more modern approach is to use `emplace` instead of `insert`.

Of course, in your case this search is redundant anyway.  Using the map `operator[]` will create a new entry if one doesn't exist.  So your whole if-else block can condense down to:

```
records[order].push_back( item );
```

Comment: That fixed the error.  Will I have to do anything different when retrieving that value with that '1' there?  Is that now just an index?

Comment: for the 'records[order]' addition you added, is that why the commented section of my code worked?  Is that good practice?

Comment: No, that was a constructor for `std::vector`.  It says to create a vector with 1 element, and make that value `item`.  I have just edited my post to suggest that you don't need to do any of this.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine.  "Good practice" probably depends a lot on your program, your data, your memory requirements, performance, and lots of other things.  But since I can tell you're new to C++, I would bet that you're not working on a huge application with hundreds of thousands of lines of code.  So you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert an `Orders`-`Items` pair into a `std::map` of `Orders`-`std::vector<Items>`. Try this instead:

```
records.insert(std::make_pair(order, std::vector<Items>(item));
```

Or store `item` in a temporary `std::vector<Items> temp` and then do,

```
records.insert(std::make_pair(order, temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a different kind of pair to the map. The map accept the pair type `<Order, vector<Item>>`. However, you are sending it the type `<Order, Item>`.

You will have to either change the kind of map you want, or the type of what you are inserting.